# How to bind data to report viewer using web-forms and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

```
// Get Issued Item (By Department Id OR By ItemId)
public DataSet GetReport(long reportNameId, int id, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, out ReportData.ReportNameDataTable reportNameDataTable)
{
        ReportData reportData = new ReportData();
        DataSet dataSet = null;
        reportNameDataTable = reportData.ReportName;
        string commandText = "GetReportNameByReportNameId";

        string[] tableName = { reportData.ReportName.TableName };
        SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper();

        try
        {
            sqlHelper.FillDataset(this.mConnectionString, commandText, reportData, tableName, reportNameId);

            if (reportData.ReportName.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                commandText = reportData.ReportName[0].ReportProcedureName;

                dataSet = sqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(this.mConnectionString, commandText, id, fromDate, toDate);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return null;
        }

        return dataSet;
}
```

This is the method what I wrote in my `ReportDataAccess.cs` class.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetReportNameByReportNameId]
    (@reportNameId AS BIGINT)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM ReportName 
    WHERE ReportNameId = @reportNameId
```

This is the stored procedure what I wrote.

Now I want to set this result data in a MS report viewer. What should I do?

I got report viewer to my toolbox

Answer (score 0):

You got data from DataSet. Now bind this data to Report Viewer DataSource. You can visit this link to refer more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8oJdFF4-IHk